# How to disable "Extraction completed successfully" dialog in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, 16.10, file-roller

In Ubuntu 16.10, every time I extract a file, Nautilus displays the dialog "Extraction completed successfully".

[image: nautilus display dialog[1]]

How can I make Nautilus finish extraction silently (like it did in 16.04)?

Comment: Were you able to find out how to do this?

Comment: OMG, this is a very annoying dialog! Posted on https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+question/443157

Comment: I'm pretty sure that dialogue comes actually from File-Roller and not from Nautilus.

Answer (score 2):

Make a wrapper and remove the --notify param:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/file-roller /usr/bin/file-roller_orig
sudo vi /usr/bin/file-roller
```

Enter the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
p1=$1
p2=$2
p3=$3
p4=$4
p5=$5
p6=$6
if [[ $p2 == *"notify"* ]]; then
        p2=""
fi
/usr/bin/file-roller_orig $p1 $p2 $p3 $p4 $p5 $p6
```

Then give the file execute permission:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/file-roller
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the file-roller source & revert this commit, then build/repackage & install

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2016-May/msg01732.html

i.e.

```
--- file-roller-3.22.2.orig/nautilus/nautilus-fileroller.c
+++ file-roller-3.22.2/nautilus/nautilus-fileroller.c
@@ -82,7 +82,7 @@ extract_here_callback (NautilusMenuItem
        dir = nautilus_file_info_get_parent_uri (file);

        cmd = g_string_new ("file-roller");
-       g_string_append_printf (cmd," --extract-here --notify");
+       g_string_append_printf (cmd," --extract-here");

        g_free (dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Neil King** for that wrapper/script - it works great BUT will only extract up to 4 archives at once. I'm no command-line guru, but I figured adding more entries past p6=$6 would work, and it did, but once you get to p9=$9 (for 7 archives), that's the max, as those with double-digits (eg: p10=$10) are ignored. So I joined up here to find out how to make this script unpack an unlimited number of archives, so this is the script code you should use if you want to achieve that too:

```
#!/bin/bash
p1=$1
p2=$2
shift 2
if [[ $p2 == *"notify"* ]]; then
        p2=""
fi
/usr/bin/file-roller_orig $p1 $p2 $@
```

Then give the file execute permission:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/file-roller
```

Many thanks to **luk3yx** for the answer at [Bash Script: How to Use Double-Digits as in “p10=$10” or Specify ALL (for File-Roller Script)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298920/bash-script-how-to-use-double-digits-as-in-p10-10-or-specify-all-for-file-r) (the script above is one I edited some quotes out of, as the original solution had too many quotes and failed with an error, but removing all the quotes besides those in the if/then line fixed it. But while the quotes aren't needed, you can view the original solution via the link above).