# How can I disable the "Extraction completed successfully" popup in File Roller Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10, archive, file-roller

When selecting a large number of archives to extract, this popup message appears as each one is extracted. After a certain number are displayed, the result is a screen full of pop-ups and the extraction process then crashes with some archives extracted and others not.

This is a real regression from previous versions where each archive would silently extract and the entire process would succeed without any crashes.

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this too. It is bloody annoying

Comment: **This issue is duplicated**. Look this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/836805/how-to-disable-extraction-completed-successfully-dialog-in-nautilus#